# Salvando linhas de um data frame baseado nos valores de uma coluna de um outro data frame

Tags: r

Tenho um *dataframe* com 50 linhas e 10 colunas e um outro com 10 linhas e 5 colunas, sendo que a primeira coluna de ambos *dataframes* podem ter valores iguais. Como faço para selecionar e salvar as linhas, apenas, do primeiro data frame seguindo a condição que devem ser iguais as linhas (da primeira coluna) do segundo data frame?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

criei dois `dataframe` para exemplificar

```
A <- data.frame(X = sample(LETTERS, 50, rep = T), Y = rnorm(50), Z = rpois(50, 3))
B <- data.frame(X1 = sample(LETTERS, 10, rep = T), Y1 = rnorm(10))
```

para você pegar as linhas da primeira coluna de `A` que tenham valores iguais nas linhas da primeira coluna de `B`, você pode usar o comando abaixo. Eu salvei em um `dataframe` `C`

```
C <- A[which(A$X %in% B$X1),]
```

Comment: Valeu! Funcionou direitinho! Obrigado, Rafael